# TS Redrawing Constantly

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, terminal-server

On one of our terminal servers, a certain client is redrawing certain windows constantly, giving the appearance of a flashing window.  It is temporarily cured by a logout and log back on, but recurres after a couple minutes.  Does anyone have any idea how to debug or fix?  Client is XP Pro SP3 w/RDCv6.  Server is 2003 SP2.

Comment: Are you sure that the application isn't trying to flash the window?

Comment: Does this happen when you run a particular application, or any time?

Comment: It happens with different programs (a LOB application, and at one point, explorer and IE).  And no, it is not trying to flash the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been quite a while since we first discovered the issue, but we did finally determine it to be caused by Windows Updates wanting to prompt the user, and not finding an explorer process.  We typically run the applications in a custom shell and only when there was no explorer.exe process would the issue occur.  Our resolution was to turn off Windows Update installation prompts for non-administrators.